# Why can't we put there's , it's , etc at the end of a sentence?

Tags: apostrophe

> I did not found any error though my teacher told there's.

Why is it grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but one would normally use _there are_ in your example, since _errors_ is plural as well. Your question remains the same, of course, because _there're_ would not feel right either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although **'s** is sometimes used to abbreviate "is," (the 3rd person singular present indicative of the verb "To be")  this usage is not acceptable in every instance. We cannot simply replace "is" with **'s** wherever it occurs.

When we use an apostrophe in this way, we call it a **contraction.** In English, we almost never end a sentence with a contraction unless it is an abbreviation of the negative word "not," which is **n't**, or, rarely, the word "have," which is **'ve**. Some examples of acceptable usage are:

> Did he win? No, he **didn't**.
>   Could he have won? Yes, he **could've**.

The technical, grammatical reasons for this are explained well [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its). For learners of English, it is enough to follow the rule:

> Never end a sentence with a contraction unless it is **n't** or **'ve**.

Answer (score 0):

The contraction "there's" is used to replace "there is" when you want to emphasize the following word (There's **nothing** wrong with this sentence. )

In your question, the word that would normally be emphasized is is itself, so you would not use the contraction: I was told by someone there is.

The thanks go to Adam for writing this text.